# Syncronize positions of 2 rectangles with different origin point while rotation

Tags: matrices, transformation, coordinate-systems, rotations

Suppose we have 2 rectangles in Cartesian coordinate system with (0,0) at the top left corner of the screen. Both of rectangles (`a` and `b`) at the same place. The first one has its origin point in top-left corner(A) and the second one in bottom-right point(B). Now I rotate them at 80 degrees CWW.

[image: rotated rectangles]

As we see `b1` now has different position then `a1`. But in my case I need `b1` will be at the same place as `a1`. So what a formula to recalculate position of a rectangle based on its origin point and angle? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rotating around the points $A$ and $B$, rectangles $a_{1}$ and $b_{1}$ can only be in the same spot when they are where rectangles $a$ and $b$ are.  So you can't rotate both rectangles and have them in the same spot unless you rotate a full 360 degrees.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm searching for the way to recalculate coordination of `b1` so that it will be placed on `a1` place. So it have to be just rotation for `a` and for `b` it's rotation + translation